# Read Excel file with blank cells as Pandas dataframe with multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose there is a Excel file:

[image]

Is there a way to read it directly as a Pandas dataframe with multiindex, without filling blank spaces in the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Data:

[image]

### Code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

#### `.ffill()`:

```
df.i0.ffill(inplace=True)
```

[image]

#### `set_index()`:

```
df.set_index(['i0', 'i1'], inplace=True)
```

[image]